# Custom Price Calculations

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am trying to figure out the best way to setup custom price calculations. Basically my product will have 5 options for example:

- Width (mm):

  Bends (Qty):

  Length: Qty:

  Straps: Yes/No

I can do these as custom options however its quite a complex calculation and needs to be carried out in a specific order. An example would be

- The width needs to be rounded up to the next 50

  Discount to be applied

  Add cost per bends (Bends worked out by £0.06/m * length)

  Multiple by Qty

  Add 10% for straps

I know how to do the calculation but just not sure the best way if integrating this with Magento.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will those width, bends etc be entered by customer while adding product to cart?

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your reply. Yes they will so basically I need to take those values and do the calculation and update the price.